# How to find the first first occurrence of a character

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple dataframe as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'BAS_DT': ['2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03'], 
                   'CUS_NAME': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                   'Y/N': ['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y'],
                   'cum_count': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2]})
df

    BAS_DT      CUS_NAME    Y/N cum_count
0   2023-01-02  A           Y   1
1   2023-01-03  A           Y   2
2   2023-01-04  A           Y   3
3   2023-01-02  B           N   1
4   2023-01-03  B           Y   2
```

I want to find the first occurrence date of `Y` in the `Y/N` column for each `CUS_NAME`. Below is my expected Output:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'BAS_DT': ['2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03'], 
                   'CUS_NAME': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                   'Y/N': ['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y'],
                   'cum_count': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2],
                   'occur_date': ['2023-01-02', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, '2023-01-03']})
df2

    BAS_DT      CUS_NAME    Y/N cum_count   occur_date
0   2023-01-02  A           Y   1           2023-01-02
1   2023-01-03  A           Y   2           NaN
2   2023-01-04  A           Y   3           NaN
3   2023-01-02  B           N   1           NaN
4   2023-01-03  B           Y   2           2023-01-03
```

How can I get this result. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
cond = df['Y/N'].eq('Y')
cond1 = cond.groupby(df['CUS_NAME']).cumsum().eq(1)
df['occur_date'] = df['BAS_DT'].where(cond & cond1)
```

df:

```
       BAS_DT CUS_NAME Y/N  cum_count  occur_date
0  2023-01-02        A   Y          1  2023-01-02
1  2023-01-03        A   Y          2         NaN
2  2023-01-04        A   Y          3         NaN
3  2023-01-02        B   N          1         NaN
4  2023-01-03        B   Y          2  2023-01-03
```

---

**Checking Example**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'BAS_DT': ['2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04'], 
                   'CUS_NAME': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'Y/N': ['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N'],
                   'cum_count': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]})
```

Comment: @hoatran The previous answer did not consider the case where B is N-Y-N.
Therefore, I have updated it to a more accurate answer.
Even if you get sufficient results with the previous code, the updated code will be more accurate.